# PHP finding @hotmail.com only from email list?

Tags: php, string

I want find hotmail email only from Email List
when I make this code,
The code post all Emails and make link on hotmail.com I want only find hotmail from email list I dont want post all emails.

**CODE:**

```
$str ="
oeirte@gmail.com
oejrteiot@hotmail.com
eoirjteit@mail.ru
ejteito@yahoo.com
";

$str2 = preg_replace('/([a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@hotmail.com)/', '<a href="$1">$1</a></br>', $str);

echo $str2;
```

How to remove another emails from the output
I want select and find hotmail emails only.

Comment: `<a href="foo@hotmail.com">foo@hotmail.com</a>` is not valid html maybe you meant  `<a href="mailto:foo@hotmail.com">foo@hotmail.com</a>` ?

Comment: Hint: For each line, if match, then make a string.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I really understood your question, but you can try the following:

```
<?php 


$str3 =array( 'oeirte@gmail.com',
             'oejrteiot@hotmail.com',
             'eoirjteit@mail.ru',
             'ejteito@yahoo.com',
             'alan@gmail.com');

foreach ($str3 as $new) {
    if (strpos($new, 'gmail') !== false) {
        echo "$new" . "  <a href=' $new'> $new</a></br>";

    }
}
```

It will print just "gmail". If it's not what you want give us more details, about what you plan to do.

See ya